# iOS 10 Notifications don't appear on the lock screen

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ios10

We are developing an iOS app and have implemented the new UNNotificationServiceExtension. We have overriden

```
func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)
```

and we call the completion handler.

We send pushes with "mutable-content" = 1

On the developer devices during the development everything worked fine.
However, when we released the app to the store on some devices users received just one notification and all of the others weren't received.

So I grabed a device, where the push notification is not shown and checked the logs:

```
Sep 16 15:47:15 my-iPhone SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[775] <Info>: Received incoming message on topic my.app.com: <private>  
Sep 16 15:47:15 my-iPhone pkd[105] <Info>: match returned 1 plug-ins  
Sep 16 15:47:15 my-iPhone accountsd(AccountsDaemon)[104] <Notice>: __48-[ACDServer listener:shouldAcceptNewConnection:]_block_invoke.246 (482) "Idle-exit-preventing transaction ended!"
```

And afterwards there are no meaningfull messages.
If I send the same push to my development device using the same push certificate and payload, then it appears on the screen and in the logs there are more messages:

```
Sep 16 15:27:12 my-iPhone SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[2727] <Info>: Received incoming message on topic my.app.com: <private>  
Sep 16 15:27:12 my-iPhone pkd[4005] <Info>: match returned 1 plug-ins  
Sep 16 15:27:12 my-iPhone SpringBoard(Foundation)[2727] <Notice>: calling plugIn beginUsing:  
Sep 16 15:27:12 my-iPhone pkd[4005] <Info>: assigning plug-in <private>(<private>) 4E733350-8D9A-4A6D-8B44-2A4C888E090C to plugin sandbox  
Sep 16 15:27:12 my-iPhone pkd[4005] <Notice>: allowing host 2727 /System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard to use plug-in <private>(<private>) uuid=4E733350-8D9A-4A6D-8B44-2A4C888E090C at <private>  
Sep 16 15:27:12 my-iPhone SpringBoard(PlugInKit)[2727] <Info>: preparing plug-in <private>(<private>)
```

As you can see on my development device it's able to call the extension, however on the non-development device it finds the plug-in (extension) but somehow is not able to start it.

Did someone experience the same issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after investigation it turned out that there was a bug in iOS 10 that prevented enabling some app extensions. 
If a user updated the app before updating to iOS 10, then new extensions did work for him.

Apple has released iOS 10.0.2 (https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1893?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) with a fix.
I have tested all of the extensions after upgrading to iOS 10.0.2 and it works fine now.